# Add an IPython console to a webpage?

Tags: embed, ipython

I would like to know if this is possible and if so, where I can find some working examples.

- Embed an IPython console on a webpage. I will also want the variables in the console to be available to the web page (i.e. javascript will be able to access ipython variables). The user of the web app will need to have ipython installed in their machine. Variables created on the webpage will also be available to the ipython console (i.e. ipython will be able to access javascript variables)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? There should be a way cause these guys seemed to figure out: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/